# The jquery code for displaying a json result not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using mvc3,razor.The link(api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=**************&location=San+Diego) is working perfectly ,I am getting json from the link, when i apply my app_key.but here i get nothing as output.I am new to jquery.Experts please help me ? Here is my code for view.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {      
        $.getJSON('http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=**************&location=San+Diego', function (data) {
            $.each(data.events.event, function (i, x) {                   
                $('<h1/>').text(x.postal_code).appendTo("#photographs")    
            });    
        });    
    });    
    </script>
    <div id="photographs"></div>
```

Below is a sample of json, it is not fully

{"last_item":null,"total_items":"6075","first_item":null,"page_number":"1","page_size":"10","page_items":null,"search_time":"0.032","page_count":"608","events":{"event":[{"watching_count":null,"calendar_count":null,"comment_count":null,"region_abbr":"CA","postal_code":"92123","going_count":null,"all_day":"0","latitude":"32.8315208","

Comment: Is `data.events.event` an array? The names suggest that `data.events` is an array, so you should iterate over that.

Comment: @Barmar
here events contains lists of event. dont know what to do ?

Comment: here is a small portion of that json  
{"last_item":null,"total_items":"6075","first_item":null,"page_number":"1","page_size":"10","page_items":null,"search_time":"0.032","page_count":"608","events":{"event":[{"watching_count":null,"calendar_count":null,"comment_count":null,"region_abbr":"CA","postal_code":"92123"

Comment: I updated my answer, but it was the same as your code, so I deleted it. 'm not sure why your code isn't working. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: one of my friend have same jquery code.but he is using flicker api.that working perfectly..but here no luck.

Comment: JSON is JSON, it doesn't matter where it came from once you decode it.

Comment: @barmar
if you have intrest in this.please create an account at api.eventful.com and they will provide you key when you request. try this.

Comment: I don't need it. I assume the JSON you posted is accurate. Did you get it by `console.log(data)` or by invoking the API by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastly by experimenting a lot i got it.

by changing

$.getJSON('http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=**************&location=San+Diego', function (data)

into

$.getJSON('http://api.eventful.com/json/events/search?app_key=**************&location=San+Diego&callback', function (data)

just need to add a callback..